# Custom config file access within Laravel 5 config files

Tags: php, laravel, config, laravel-5

I created custom config file in **Laravel 5** and try to use settings from it in other files (`session.php`, `cache.php`) by calling `config('myconfigfile.value')`, but there are no values returned from my config. It seems that config files have predefined loading order and custom configs is loading in the end or it didn't initialized else by other cause.

How can I access to my settings from laravel config files?

Answer (score 11):

First you need add the file in the config folder for example: laravel\config\Test.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;


return [

    'name' => 'Ali Mohammed',
    'age' => 26

];
```

then you need to call the config

```
get('test', function(){

   return  Config::get('Test.name');

});
```

Comment: I have no problem to get settings from my custom configs in any part of application except standard laravel config files. Try to access your `'Test.name'` from `'config/cache.php'`.

Comment: that true sorry for misunderstanding the question I'am not sure but i think you can not call config inside another config file as you said It seems that config files have predefined loading order.

Answer (score 5):

We should also check the cache for custom config files added.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the `env()` helper within every configuration file you need?

You would just have to set the value in your `.env` file

```
CUSTOM_SETTING="some value"
```

and get it on each configuration file

```
<?php
return [
    // ...
    'custom_value' => env('CUSTOM_SETTING', 'some default value'),
    // ...
];
```

Have a look at the [helper code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L595).

Comment: Config file is the main place to store settings of application and `.env` file is for correct some settings if necessary. Application should work properly without any `.env` file.
To guarantee app works without `.env` file using your approach I should edit every occurrence of `'some default value'` in configs instead edit only `config/custom-config.php`.
Yes, it isn't hard, but I think it isnt't the best way.

Comment: To achieve what you want, there's no other way I know of. Also, what's the point of assigning a value from a config file to a different config file value? You say my suggestion isn't the best way, yet what you ask is completely redundant! Care to explain what's the reasoning behind what you want? Otherwise, what I suggested is the most correct way you'll probably get.

Comment: No, it is not redundant for me :)
For example, I have application name value in custom config and I want to generate session file name or cache prefix according this value.

Comment: If the application name is gonna change all the time, you might as well use `.env` files, in which case you would just do something like `'files' => storage_path().'/framework/sessions/'.env('APP_NAME'),`. If the application name isn't gonna change, just pass the value directly: `'files' => storage_path().'/framework/sessions/app_name',`.